# How can I make my current code use Multithreading/concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures, netmiko

I am new to netmiko/Python  scripting , Using online examples was able to make a script to take configuration backup. The backup is copied to the text file and output is saved.

Currently this backup is done sequentially and it does not connect to all device at once and take the backup. I want to connect to all the devices concurrently.

I understand multithreading or concurrent.futures can solve this issue`enter code here` but I was not able to do it so far.

Can anyone please suggest, how my existing code can be modified to achieve it. Below is the code.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoTimeoutException
from paramiko.ssh_exception import SSHException
from netmiko.ssh_exception import AuthenticationException
import getpass
import sys
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime

##getting system date 
day=time.strftime('%d')
month=time.strftime('%m')
year=time.strftime('%Y')
today=day+"-"+month+"-"+year
enter code here
##initialising device
 device = {
'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
'ip': '192.168.100.21',
'username': 'Cisco',
'password': 'Cisco',
'secret':'Cisco',
'session_log': 'log.txt'
}
##opening IP file
ipfile=open("iplist.txt")
print ("Script to take backup of devices, Please enter your credential")
device['username']=input("username ")
device['password']=getpass.getpass()
print("Enter enable password: ")
device['secret']=getpass.getpass()enter code here

##taking backup
for line in ipfile:
 try:
 device['ip']=line.strip("\n")
 print("\n\nConnecting Device ",line)
 net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
 net_connect.enable()
 time.sleep(1)

 with open('config.txt') as f:
    cmd = f.read().splitlines()
 print ("Reading the running config ")
 output = net_connect.send_config_set(cmd)
 output4 = "Failed"
 time.sleep(7)    
 filename=device['ip']+'-'+today+".txt"
 folder = os.path.join(today)
 file = os.path.join(folder,filename)
 os.makedirs(folder,exist_ok=True)
 saveconfig=open(file,'w+')
 print("Writing Configuration to file")
 saveconfig.write(output)
 saveconfig.close()
 time.sleep(10)
 net_connect.disconnect()
      
 print ("Configuration saved to file",filename)   
 except:
      print ("Access to "+device['ip']+" failed,backup did not taken")
      output4 = "Failed"
      file= device['ip']+'-'+today+"Error"+".txt"
      config=open(file,'w+')
      config.write(output4)
      config.close()
      
     ipfile.close()
     print ("\nAll device backup completed")enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code, you can run commands on many devices at the same time. You can also use it by hiding your identity information with user_pass. There is also a device prompt discovery feature.

with open("user_pass.txt", "r") as f5:
user_pass = f5.readlines()

for list_user_pass in user_pass:
if "username" in list_user_pass:
username = list_user_pass.split(":")[1].strip()
if "password" in list_user_pass:
password = list_user_pass.split(":")[1].strip()

```
   def _ssh_(nodeip):
       try:
       access_mpls = {
           'device_type': 'huawei_olt', 'ip': nodeip, 'username':
               username, 'password': password, }
       net_connect = Netmiko(**access_mpls)
       print(nodeip.strip() + "  " + "success enter")
   except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       f_3.write(nodeip.strip() + "\n")
       return

   prompt_gpon_fnk = net_connect.find_prompt()
   hostname_fnk = prompt_gpon_fnk.strip("<" + ">")
   print(hostname_fnk)
   net_connect.send_command_timing("enable")
   net_connect.send_command_timing("undo smart")
   output = net_connect.send_command_timing("config")
   print("config moda girildi")
   net_connect.send_command_timing("acl 2010 ")
   net_connect.send_command_timing("quit")
   net_connect.send_command_timing("save")

   print("config done")
   with open("MDU_OK_2.txt", "a") as f:
       f.write(nodeip + "\n")
       f.close()

   net_connect.disconnect()
```

f_2 = open("ip_list_2.txt", "r") ip_list = f_2.readlines()
f_2.close() f_3 = open("ssh_unsuccess_2.txt", "w")

myPool = ThreadPool(100) result = myPool.map(*ssh*, ip_list)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below script and modify it according to your requirement. Here I have used python `multiprocessing` for connecting devices in pools.

```
#This script will allow for user pick hosts and enter show commands interactively
#
#Enable Multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
#
#getpass will not display password
from getpass import getpass
#ConnectionHandler is the function used by netmiko to connect to devices
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
#Time tracker
from time import time

#create variables for username and password
#create variables for configs and hosts
uname = input("Username: ")
passwd = getpass("Password: ")
cmd = input("Enter show commands seperated by ',': ")
host = input("Enter the host IPs seperate with space: ")

#This will put hosts and commands entered into list format
hosts = host.split()
cmds = cmd.split(",")

starting_time = time()

#Each member of the pool of 5 will be run through this function
def run_script(host_ip):
    ios_rtr = {
        "device_type": "cisco_ios",
        "ip": host_ip,
        "username": uname,
        "password": passwd,
        }
    #connect to the device via ssh
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**ios_rtr)
    #print the device IP or Hostname
    print("Connected to host:", host_ip)
    #this for loop is used to iterate through the show commands
    for show_commands in cmds:
        output = net_connect.send_command(show_commands)
        print("Connected to host:", host_ip)
        print(output)
        print('\n---- Elapsed time=', time()-starting_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Pool(5) means 5 process will be run at a time, more hosts will go in the next group
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(run_script, hosts))


#This is the key to sending show commands vs config commands
#show commands --> net_connect.send_command()
#config commmands --> net_connect.send_config_set()
```